# C# uploading file to a Filezilla Server (XAMPP) error: Impossible to write data on transport connection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to upload a file using FTP to my server (I have built it with xampp so it has Apache and FileZilla server ).

A C# app works good for some hours then I get this exception and the app stops uploading the file.

(I'm keeping the connection alive. The code is debugged and consistent. I did some tests on other machines with xampp and had the same problem.)

This is the message returned:

```
System.Net.WebException: Eccezione durante una richiesta WebClient. ---> System.IO.IOException: Impossibile scrivere dati sulla connessione di trasporto: Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto
in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- Fine dell'analisi dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
in System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
in System.Net.FtpDataStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
in System.Net.WebClient.UploadBitsState.WriteBytes()
in System.Net.WebClient.UploadBits(WebRequest request, Stream readStream, Byte[] buffer, Byte[] header, Byte[] footer, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
in System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
--- Fine dell'analisi dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
in System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
```

Comment: Can you change your language settings to English and re-generate the error?

Comment: This walk-through also suggests checking some properties of the exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ww3ee9(v=vs.80).aspx